# Is it possible to disable the splash screen of ChemDraw?

Tags: software

Is it possible to disable the splash screen of ChemDraw? I can't find a corresponding setting in the preferences dialog. Is there maybe a hidden setting / some configuration file that can be modified?

Answer (score 1):

I *assume* the question seeks out for a way to use ChemDraw more quickly, for example while being confronted with a larger number of chemical structures already generated, and to be processed further.  Then

- If it is to browse through a number of structures aiming "to find the right file", to gain an overview, then [Thumbfish](https://abhimanyusirohi.github.io/ThumbFish/) (Windows only) may be helpful.  [Chemdoodle](https://www.chemdoodle.com/) (Win/Mac/Linux) and [MarvinSketch](http://www.chemaxon.com/products/marvin/marvinsketch/) offer in their file-open menu a [preview](http://www.gunda.hu/dprogs/#data) as well.
- On the other hand, provided the extensive documentation especially of ChemDraw seconds native, the [*.cdxml](http://www.cambridgesoft.com/services/documentation/sdk/chemdraw/cdx/General.htm) format, the (batchwise) conversion into other formats is easily done with [OpenBabel](http://openbabel.org/wiki/Main_Page) ([supported file formats](http://openbabel.org/docs/2.3.0/FileFormats/Overview.html)) and Apple Script [ChemBot](https://github.com/metamolecular/chembot/) (application [here](http://metamolecular.com/blog/2011/07/18/chembot-convert-chemdraw-cdx-files-into-png-images-using-applescript/)).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I am indeed looking for a way to use ChemDraw more quickly. However, I am manually creating/editing many structures..